# Action doesn't load the view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

there!

It's a MVC app with jQuery.

With this Action in my Controller I expect to create an object and then open a view to edit that object:

```
    public ActionResult GetUserFromAD(string logon)
    {
        var userAD = new UsersAD().ListUsersFromAD(logon).FirstOrDefault();
        var userApp = new User();
        userApp .Logon = userAD .Login;
        userApp .Nome = userAD .DisplayName;
        userApp .Divisao = userAD .Orgao;
        userApp .Email = userAD .Email;
        return View(userApp );
    }
```

I call this Action from this jQuery from the click on an  element in another view:

```
$(document).on("click", ".GetUserFromAD", function () {        
    var options = {};
    options.url = "/Administracao/GetUserFromAD";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.data = { logon: $(this).attr("data-id") };
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.contentType = "application/json";
    //options.success = function (data) {

    //};
    options.error = function () { alert("Error on getting user data from AD!") };
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

Well, the fact is that the expected view is never loaded, although the parameter logon is ok, the object userApp is also ok.

All I get is just this alert from the jQuery function (Error on getting ...).

What am I missing? What should I do to have the view opened properly?

Thanks for your time.

Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint on your action in the controller and seeing if the action gets hit? If so is there an error in your server side code? Also uncomment your success method and put an alert(data) - that should respond with the HTML that you need to embed.

Comment: @Gjohn, thanks for your time. I added a breakpoint in the action and verified that the action is hit, and the object userAD is properly retrieved (server-side code with no error). Uncommented the success method and still getting the same response.

Comment: is there any error happening on the view itself? Could you post what your view looks like? Also look at fiddler to see what exactly is being returned from your call to the action. Also change your contentType to "text/html"

Comment: Notice that the ajax method is type GET. I just want the action to render the view.

Comment: I changed the contentType to "text/html" as you suggested and made no diference.

Comment: Except with an Ajax call your action is going to return your view back to the success function. You are changing the content type because in the way you have it coded your response from the server is going to be the HTML of the view. It won't be a JSON result.

Comment: So, how should I code it so I just have the view rendered with its content?

Comment: If you are going with it using Ajax then see my answer below. The question I have is are you trying to render just a partial view or are you trying to redirect to another view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working. It opens the view with the respctive data.

The code of my jQuery function is as bellow:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".GetUserFromAD", function () { 
    var logon = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var targetUrl = "/Administracao/CreateUserOnApp/?logon=" + logon.toString();
    window.location.href = targetUrl;
});
```

And the code in action is as:

```
        public ActionResult CreateUserOnApp(string logon)
    {
        var userAD = new UsuariosAD().ListUsersFromAD(logon).FirstOrDefault();
        var userApp = new User();
        userApp .Logon = userAD .Login;
        userApp .Nome = userAD .DisplayName;
        userApp .Divisao = userAD .Orgao;
        userApp .Email = userAD .Email;
        return View(userApp );
    }
```

Now it works the way I expected.

Thanks for all of you that helped me to find the way to accomplish this.

Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested solution hopefully this works for you:

```
$(document).on("click", ".GetUserFromAD", function () {        
var options = {};
options.url = "/Administracao/GetUserFromAD";
options.type = "GET";
options.data = { logon: $(this).attr("data-id") };
options.dataType = "json";
options.contentType = "text/html";
options.success = function (data) {
   $('....container where you want your view to show up .....').html(data);
};
options.error = function () { alert("Error on getting user data from AD!") };
$.ajax(options);
});
```

### UPDATE

The other option is to do an ajax call but do not return anything. Instead Redirect to another action that will load the view you want to use

```
return RedirectToAction(Action name, model);
```

Comment: I tried your latest suggestion. In my original action, now I have this `return RedirectToAction("CreateUserOnApp", usuarioApp);` and the _CreateUserOnApp_ action has just this: `return View(user)`. Even so, it didn't work. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is the CreateUserOnApp action located in the same controller? What is happening when you do the redirect? Is the action getting hit? If not check your routing rules.

Comment: BTW - is "CreateUserOnApp" the View that you want to load? Is there a view by the name of "CreateUserOnApp." If not what is the name of the view?

Comment: the answer to all the above questions is **yes**! The action **is** in the same controller; the action **gets hit**; the CreateUserOnApp **is** the view I want to load and **there is** a view by the name of CreateUserOnApp. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What I get from the javascript code is a **parsererror**